# dpkg: error processing package php7.0 (--configure)

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg

I was doing `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and I pressed `ctrl + c` by mistake, after that a ran into [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process), I "solved" it doing the zurdo solution (first anwser, sorted by votes), but now can't solve:

```
...
dpkg: error processing package php7.0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php7.0-common
 php7.0-cli
 libapache2-mod-php7.0
 php7.0-cgi
 php7.0
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I think that when I pressed ctrl-c it was updating php-cli, here is an image with more information.

[image]

I'm running Xubuntu 16.04

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get -f install` and try again `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Same message for `... -f install`, update looks fine. I really want to avoid reinstalling these packages. Thanks @M.Becerra

Comment: Please paste terminal text directly instead of making screenshots of it. https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/250300

Comment: @Melebius I know the rules, I just posted the image to be a backup. It would become too extense and I don't think it's that importante (not really a copy/paste text). Anyway, thanks for the tip